# xNormal black squares

Tags: ambient-occlusion

I'm having issues where there are lines of dark squares when I'm rendering my ambient occlusion and vertex colors in xNormal. They look like this:

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]

And for the record this is what my normal looks like, if that's any help:

[image: Img3]

The squares don't align with the low poly, but they do with the high poly, thought its with the lowest subdivision level. The cavity map seems fine:

[image: Img4]

so I don't know why the id map and AO map are acting up. Iv'e messed with the closest hit if ray fails and the discard back face hits, and they do not do anything. Could it be a case of flipped normals in zbrush?

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about Blender :(  I would recommend taking your low and high poly mesh into Blender and inspect it check it for flipped normals remove any unnecessary sharp edges and create a custom cage that can be used by Xnormal. Try baking in Blender and see what results you get another alternative baking tool you can try is Handplane,